# How to start launch puppeteer before using it

Tags: node.js, puppeteer

I am currently working on a web-scraping project and need to reduce waiting time to as little as possible.
Since I am making a restful API I want to launch puppeteer before someone makes a request.
This way I hope that the chrome is already launched which could potentially save much time.

I am however not very experienced with node and could use some help. The code below does not work, but illustrates somewhat what I am trying to approach.

```
const puppeteer = require('puppeteer');
var readlineSync = require('readline-sync');
var x = undefined;
var browser = async () => {
    x = await puppeteer.launch();
    if (x != null){
       resolve(return x);
    }
    else{
       reject(console.log('failed promise'));
    }
}
exports.getInfo = (url) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.goto(url, { waitUntil: 'networkidle2' });
        await page.keyboard.press('Escape');
        await page.keyboard.press('PageDown');
        await page.keyboard.press('PageDown');
        await page.waitForXPath("//div[starts-with(@class, 'detail-desc-decorate-')] | //p[starts-with(@class, 'detail-desc-decorate-')] | //div[@id='product-description']//p");

        let data = await page.evaluate(() => {
            let images = [];
            for (i = 0; i < document.querySelectorAll('div.images-view-item > img').length; i++) {
                link = document.querySelectorAll('div.images-view-item > img')[i].src;
                images[i] = link;
            }

            var json = JSON.stringify({
                title: document.querySelector('div.product-title').innerText,
                description: document.querySelector('div[id=product-description]').innerText,
                price: document.querySelector('div.product-price-current').innerText,
                productOption: document.querySelector('div.product-sku').innerHTML,
                //shippingCost: document.querySelector('div.product-shipping-price').innerText,
                //deliviryDate: document.querySelector('span.product-shipping-delivery > span').innerText,
                mainImage: document.querySelector('img.magnifier-image').src,
                images: images
            });
            return json
        })

        await browser.close();
        if (data != null) {
            resolve(console.log('yay'));
        } else {
            reject(console.log('failed promise'));
        }
    })
}
browser().then(console.log(x)).catch(console.log('something went horribly wrong'))
```

Hope that this somewhat demonstrates my goal.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You're close. Try changing your `browser` function to this so that it launches exactly once:

```
let browser;
const launchBrowser = async () => {
    if (browser) return;
    browser = await puppeteer.launch();
};
```

and then in `getInfo`, await the launch (will be immediate except for the first time):

```
exports.getInfo = (url) => {
    return new Promise(async (resolve, reject) => {
        await launchBrowser();
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        // ...
```

and remove `await browser.close()` from the end of `getInfo`.

Comment: You suggestion reduced loading time form +- 5 seconds to about 2 seconds!