# Timeout task after deploy to Netify successful

Tags: node.js, puppeteer, netlify

Hello stackoverflow users. Im doing some side-project with scraping dynamic contents page with `chrome-aws-lambda`.
After i success to deploy to netlify. Somehow, i get error `ERROR  Task timed out after 10.01 seconds` randomly. . I tried with local development and still working normal ( you can see the log below).

I was follow-up [this topic](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60121944/how-to-start-launch-puppeteer-before-using-it) to make my function run-once ( to reduce the load time too) but still get the error

```
> netlify dev
◈ Netlify Dev ◈
◈ Ignored general context env var: LANG (defined in process)
◈ Ignored general context env var: LANGUAGE (defined in process)
◈ No app server detected and no "command" specified
◈ Using current working directory
◈ Unable to determine public folder to serve files from
◈ Setup a netlify.toml file with a [dev] section to specify your dev server settings.
◈ See docs at: https://cli.netlify.com/netlify-dev#project-detection
◈ Running static server from "scrap-nodeJS"
◈ Loaded function cases.
◈ Loaded function hello.
◈ Functions server is listening on 37945

◈ Server listening to 3999

   ┌─────────────────────────────────────────────────┐
   │                                                 │
   │   ◈ Server now ready on http://localhost:8888   │
   │                                                 │
   └─────────────────────────────────────────────────┘

◈ Rewrote URL to /.netlify/functions/hello
Request from ::1: GET /.netlify/functions/hello
Response with status 200 in 21 ms.
◈ Rewrote URL to /.netlify/functions/cases
Request from ::1: GET /.netlify/functions/cases
Done
Response with status 200 in 2997 ms.
```

This is my current code :

```js
const chromium = require('chrome-aws-lambda');
exports.handler = async function (event, context) {
    let browser;
    const launchBrowser = async () => {
        if (browser) return;
        browser = await chromium.puppeteer.launch({
            executablePath: await chromium.executablePath,
            args: chromium.args,
            defaultViewport: chromium.defaultViewport,
            headless: true,
        });
    };
    try {
        await launchBrowser()
        const page = await browser.newPage();
        await page.setRequestInterception(true);
        page.on('request', (req) => {
// prevent render css,img,only render text
            if (req.resourceType() === 'stylesheet' || req.resourceType() == 'font' || req.resourceType() == 'image') {
                req.abort();
            } else {
                req.continue();
            }
        });
        await page.goto('https://vnexpress.net/covid-19/covid-19-viet-nam');
        const element = await page.waitForSelector('.total_case_today'); // select the element
        const cases = await element.evaluate(el => el.textContent); // grab the textContent from the 
        return {
            statusCode: 200,
            body: JSON.stringify({
                cases: cases
            }),

        };
    } catch (error) {
        console.log(error);
    } finally {
        console.log("Done");
    }
};
```

Answer (score 0):

It s beacause you never close the browser so it taking more and more memory after every calls and it finish to blow the memory and crash the instance.

Behind the magnicness of lambda there is the reality of the the IT, the function instance will be the same most of the time so you need to close the browser properly to free the memory.